# FATAL: Module bcm2708_wdog not found

Tags: raspbian, watchdog

I would like to install watchdog timer on Raspbian Wheezy, but when I execute:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2708_wdog
```

I get:

```
FATAL: Module bcm2708_wdog not found.
```

uname -a

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.7-v7+ #878 SMP Tue Apr 19 19:03:45 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

How can I load Module bcm2708_wdog?

Answer (score 8):

> how i can load Module bcm2708_wdog

At first I thought you were looking for the wrong thing because of this:

> ```
> Linux raspberrypi 4.4.7-v7+
>                         ^^^
> ```

Since this means you are using a Pi 2 or 3, parts for which are sometimes referred to as "2709" instead of "2708".  However, [as far as I can tell](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/modules/4.4.7%2B/kernel/drivers), the watchdog module has the same name for both of them:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835_wdt
```

And there are no `wdog` [aliases](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/modules/4.4.7%2B/modules.alias) defined either.

There is a lot of (older?) documentation online referring to the module you are trying to load though.  Perhaps something changed at some point, or that was built into the kernel.

Comment: FWIW, when I viewed my modules with `lsmod` on my RPi3, `bcm2835_wdt` was already loaded in.

Answer (score 1):

From this: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1285#issuecomment-182264729

That is, add:

```
dtparam=watchdog=on
```

to the end of /boot/config.txt

```
$ ls -l /dev/wat*
crw------- 1 root root  10, 130 May 20 01:28 /dev/watchdog
crw------- 1 root root 253,   0 May 20 01:28 /dev/watchdog0
```

Comment: did not help for me

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are using the latest development kernel (OK 4.4 should be released shortly) but still trying to use old tools and methods.

You should enable via Device Tree.

In any event you should stick to the release OS unless you have some particular reason to run development.

AFAIK 4.4 drops the duplicate 2708 modules (which were always incorrectly named).